# What are the Visual Studio's Package Manager Console (Powershell) limitations?

Tags: visual-studio, limit, visual-studio-2019, package-manager-console

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell) Package Manager Console helps with package management. It also allows issuing migration related commands (e.g. `Add-Migration`).

I was fooling around by trying its limits and have noticed that some Powershell commands simply do not work (indefinite wait). Example (trying to open a shell within a container):

```
docker exec -it catalogdb /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa
```

I pretty sure I have encountered other limitations in the past.

I tried finding out what are the known limitations of this console, since in many cases it is more convenient to run Powershell commands from Visual Studio, but could not find any relevant documentation.

**Question:** What are the Visual Studio's Package Manager Console (Powershell) limitations? (as opposed to Windows Powershell console)

Comment: I know that access to some features are limited. I can for instance `import-module WebAdministration` (if running visual studio as admin) but when trying to run any cmdlets, like `Get-Website` or `Get-Webitemstate` i get errors.
I can use these cmdlets in a normal powershell (admin) window. (the IISAdministration module seems to work though)